# How to remove the tools buttons in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

[image: Tools windows]

How to remove the tools button from PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Click the place indicated in the picture.

Comment: Or you can [disable it in settings](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/9605/lplm.png).